# JQuery Datatables not working on ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I've used the nuget Package Manager Console with the command `install-package jquerydatatablesmvc` to install jquery datatables to my MVC 5 project and it installed version 1.9.4.

However, after including the required scripts and css files, the data table is not still working.

Here is what I've added to the page:

```
<link href="~/Content/DataTables-1.9.4/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

And the jquery code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTable').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Here is the actual table:

```
<table class="table" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Registered By</th>
            <th>Is Active</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
           @foreach (var m in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => m.Name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => m.RegisteredBy)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => m.IsActive)</td>
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = m.Id }) | 
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = m.Id }) | 
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = m.Id })</td>
                </tr>
            }

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Where did I mess up?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console in the browser?

Comment: Oh, I didn't check that. Now, it says "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function"

Comment: Do you have any other references to jQuery? (I see the one in your code snippet, but are there other references to it in the page?) If you have multiple references to jQuery, this could be causing it

Comment: There is this line on the master layout page :     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

Comment: Ok, try removing the <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.js"></script> tag. If your jquery bundle is using a compatible version of Jquery, it should work fine.

Comment: Now, the exception is changed to: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined and Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: that last error means that jQuery is now not initialised. Can you verify your ~/bundles/jQuery bundle is referencing jQuery, and that it appears above the data tables script tag? If so, then you may need to post your page's html source code (as rendered by the browser) - just the script tags and associated data tables.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now, it's working. I just put jquery reference on the master page before the bundle and added the jquery-datatable reference below the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have explained [here](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2015/11/implement-jquery-datatable-in-aspnet-mvc.html) how to implement jQuery DataTable in asp.net MVC application step by step.

just follow a few steps for doing that work in your application

Step 1 : Write a MVC action for fetch data from database

```
public ActionResult loaddata()
{
 using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
  {
    var data = dc.Customers.OrderBy(a => a.ContactName).ToList();
    return Json(new { data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

Step 2 : Write html and jQuery for show database data

Complete HTML code

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Part 1 : Implement jQuery Datatable in ASP.NET MVC</h2>
<div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
   <table id="myTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Employee Name</th>
          <th>Company</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th>Country</th>
          <th>City</th>
          <th>Postal Code</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
 </table>
</div>
<style>
  tr.even {
   background-color: #F5F5F5 !important;
 }
</style>
@* Load datatable css *@
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@* Load datatable js *@
@section Scripts{
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
        "url": "/home/loaddata",
        "type": "GET",
        "datatype": "json"
      },
        "columns" : [
           { "data": "ContactName", "autoWidth": true },
           { "data": "CompanyName", "autoWidth": true },
           { "data": "Phone", "autoWidth": true },
           { "data": "Country", "autoWidth": true },
           { "data": "City", "autoWidth": true },
           { "data": "PostalCode", "autoWidth": true }
        ]
     });
   });
 </script>
}
```

Comment: Although your answer may be correct, it is good to explain what the issue was with the original question. If you could point out the line where the error was or explain a concept or step that was missed, this would be more helpful for the user then posting a step by step tutorial.